# ExcelJs not writing to excel

Tags: javascript, electron, exceljs

I'm having an issue with ExcelJS, here is my code:

```js
ipcMain.on('sendTimeData', async (event, { username, client, activity, startTime, finishTime }) => {
  try {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile('excel.xlsx');
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(username);
    
    if (!worksheet) {
      worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(username);
     
      worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Day', key: 'Day', width: 10 },
        { header: 'Starting_time', key: 'Starting_time', width: 18 },
        { header: 'Finishing_time', key: 'Finishing_time', width: 18 },
        { header: 'Client', key: 'Client', width: 15 },
        { header: 'Activity', key: 'Activity', width: 30 },
        { header: 'User', key: 'User', width: 15 },
      ];
    }
  
    worksheet.addRow({
      Day: startTime.toString(),
      Starting_time: startTime.toString(),
      Finishing_time: finishTime.toString(),
      Client: client,
      Activity: activity,
      User: username,
    });
    
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('excel.xlsx');
    console.log('Data added to Excel file.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    event.reply('sendTimeDataError', error.message);
  }
});
```

I want to add all the the variables definied like Day, Starting_time ... etc.
So it even creates a new worksheet if a user doesn't exist but my code doesn't add anything. I have preformatted as all the headers as a table just like referenced, but it never adds a row.